# Why doesn't TypeScript offer a strongly typed try-catch clause?

Tags: typescript

Consider this hypothetical try-catch block:

```
try {
  ...
} catch (e: MyError) {
  ...
} catch (e: string) {
  ...
}
```

equivalent to

```
try {
  ...
} catch (e) {
  if (e instanceof MyError) {
    ...
  } else if (typeof e === 'string') {
    ...
  } else {
    throw e;
  }
}
```

I find the former much clearer and more succinct, both in the expression of what is meant to be handled and in the intent of forwarding all other exceptions.

Has this been considered in TypeScript? It seems to me that it would be relatively straightforward to compile the former code into the latter.

Is there perhaps some general rationale why such a deviation from JavaScript syntax would be undesirable?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals

Comment: I guess, because TS only adds types, and doesn't add syntactic sugar (anymore)

Comment: @jonrsharpe +1 for the resource. `Provide a structuring mechanism for larger pieces of code.` would apply and `Avoid adding expression-level syntax.` wouldn't (right?). Non-goal `Exactly mimic the design of existing languages. [...]` applies but only by happenstance (C++), it's not the point at all. I find the non-goal `Introduce behavior that is likely to surprise users.` to apply *by omission* right now: not adding a clean syntax for typing exceptions, when a lot of syntax has been added for typing everything else, is surprising (especially since it seems straightforward to do).